# jquery namespaced events

Tags: jquery

How do I have a widget listen for clicks on other widgets but not listen to normal clicks on itself. For example:

```
var $dialogWidget = jQuery('#dialogWidget');

$dialogWidget
  .bind('click.btn1.otherWidget',doSomething)
  .bind('click.btn2.otherWidget',doSomething2)
  .bind('click.btn1.otherWidget2',doSomething3);
```

The problem with this code is that when I click anywhere on $dialogWidget, all of these events that I have bound will be triggered. What I want is this

```
var $otherWidget = jQuery('#otherWidget');
var $btn1 = $otherWidget.find('a.btn1');
$btn1
    .click(function(){
        $dialogWidget.trigger('click.btn1.otherWidget');
     });
```

This should be the only way that 'click.btn1.otherWidget' event is fired for $dialogWidget.

One possible thing I could do that would be a hack is anytime I am manually firing a click event is to use 'clicked' instead of click, but that feels like a hack. Any ideas?

Comment: apparrently jQuery supports exclusive events. So $dialogWidget.trigger('click!') would only trigger the 'click' and not 'click.namespace' events. I need the opposite of this. Something like $dialogWidget.bind('click.namespace!') which would mean only items that manually fire this the fully qualified event would trigger this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to rename your events, use a name that's not taken.  In this case, just don't use `click`, do something like this instead:

```
$dialogWidget
  .bind('myClick.btn1.otherWidget',doSomething)
  .bind('myClick.btn2.otherWidget',doSomething2)
  .bind('myClick.btn1.otherWidget2',doSomething3);
```

Then when you trigger it:

```
$dialogWidget.trigger('myClick.btn1.otherWidget');
```

This was `click` won't trigger your namespace custom events that you don't want fired any other way.  To be clear this isn't a hack, it's **completely normal** jQuery behavior, it's intentionally supported throughout the jQuery event model.  [Google for `jQuery custom events`](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+custom+events), there are a lot of resources out there around this.

Comment: Thanks again Nick, I guess I just wanted to see if there were other ways to do this. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You could use event delegation here and try to handle what to do by `event.target` property.

```
var $widgets = jQuery('.widget');
$widgets.click(function(event){
  if($(event.target).attr("id") !== "dialogWidget"){
      alert("You won't see this alert if you click on #dialogWidet");
  }
});
```

This might help you.